# AWS SWF Find Child Workflow Instance / runid

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

If I have created a child workflow using StartChildWorkflowExecution now in the parent workflow while handling a signal how do I find if there is any Child workflow running and if yes whats it's runid so that I can send signal or terminate the child workflow?

I am using .Net SDK not the flow framework.

Comment: Does .Net SDK provide high level API like the Flow Framework or you implement your workflow against the raw history?

Comment: no .net SDK doesn't provide high level API like Flow Framework, we implemented against workflow raw history. Does this mean I need to log myslef in a marker?

Answer (score 0):

When there is [ChildWorkflowExecutionStarted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ChildWorkflowExecutionStartedEventAttributes.html) event (which contains runId of the child) and there is no [ChildWorkflowExecutionCompleted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ChildWorkflowExecutionCompletedEventAttributes.html) (or similar) event in the history then child workflow is still running. These events are delivered asynchronously to the parent workflow, so it could be that child has terminated and parent still wasn't notified. But this window is usually pretty short.